# Relative acceleration of two planets orbiting a star

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration, celestial-mechanics, coriolis-effect

Let us suppose we know the radii and periods of two planets' circular orbits around a star -say Earth, Venus and the Sun-, which allows us to calculate the planets' centripetal acceleration, respectively $\mathbf{a}_{ES}$ and $\mathbf{a}_{VS}$, toward the Sun.

I would like to understand how we can calculate the acceleration $\mathbf{a}_{VE}$ of Venus with respect to Earth.

I might be tempted to say $\mathbf{a}_{VE}=\mathbf{a}_{VS}-\mathbf{a}_{ES}$, naïvely, but I know that the acceleration of a generic point $P$ with respect to a frame $A$, with respect to which frame $B$ is moving, can be expressed as
 $$\mathbf{a}_{PA}=\mathbf{a}_{PB}+\Big(\frac{d\boldsymbol{\omega}_{BA}}{dt} \Big)_A\times\mathbf{r}_{PB}+\Big(\frac{d^2(\mathbf{r}_{PA}-\mathbf{r}_{PB})}{dt^2} \Big)_A+\boldsymbol{\omega}_{BA}\times(\boldsymbol{\omega}_{BA}\times\mathbf{r}_{PB})+\mathbf{a}_C$$ where the last term is the Coriolis acceleration$$ \mathbf{a}_C=2\boldsymbol{\omega}_{BA}\times\mathbf{v}_{PB}$$and where $\mathbf{r}_{PQ}$, respectively $\mathbf{v}_{PQ}$, $\mathbf{a}_{PQ}$ and $\boldsymbol{\omega}_{PQ}$ are the position, velocity, acceleration and angular velocity of $P$ with respect to $Q$.

Therefore I would set $P=V$, $A=E$ and $B=S$, but I have some problem in identifying what the various terms of the equality would be, for example how $$\Big(\frac{d^2(\mathbf{r}_{VE}-\mathbf{r}_{VS})}{dt^2} \Big)_E,$$ which is, if I correctly understand, the derivative of the position of the origin of the frame of the Sun with respect to the frame of Earth, would be, and so on for the other terms. I heartily thank you for any answer!

Comment: If you're considering circular orbits, yes, the $d\omega/dt$ terms for $\omega_{SE}$ and $\omega_{SV}$ would be zero. Wouldn't the second derivative example you list simply be the centripetal acceleration of the Earth (with proper sign)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I have found how to evaluate the relative acceleration. If we place the origin in the centre of Earth according to a geocentric model, the curve described by Venus is $$\mathbf{r}_{VE}(t)=R_E\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\omega_{E}t+\varphi_1)\\\sin(\omega_{E}t+\varphi_1)\end{pmatrix} + R_V\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\omega_{V}t+\varphi_2)\\\sin(\omega_{V}t+\varphi_2)\end{pmatrix}$$for some angles $\varphi_1,\varphi_2$, and therefore$$\mathbf{r}_{VE}''(t)=-R_T\omega_{E}^2\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\omega_{E}t+\varphi_1)\\\sin(\omega_{E}t+\varphi_1)\end{pmatrix} - R_V\omega_{V}^2\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\omega_{V}t+\varphi_2)\\\sin(\omega_{V}t+\varphi_2)\end{pmatrix}.$$